# Sorting a column in pandas is just returning the same unsorted information

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am using pandas_datareader to pull yahoo stock data and calculate percent change. Now i want to take those percent change values and sort them from lowest to highest and put the sorted data in a new column. The column is being made but the values are not sorted, just copied over.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
Ticker = 'SQ'

result = pdr.get_data_yahoo(Ticker) 
result = result.drop(['Open','High','Low','Volume','Adj Close'], axis=1)
result['pct change'] = (result.pct_change(1,'pad'))*100
result['Sorted'] = result['pct change'].sort_values(inplace = False)
```

The first few lines of output however look like this

```
                Close  pct change    Sorted
Date                                                   
2017-07-17  26.190001         NaN         NaN
2017-07-18  26.590000    1.527297    1.527297
2017-07-19  26.360001   -0.864983   -0.864983
2017-07-20  26.389999    0.113801    0.113801
2017-07-21  26.850000    1.743088    1.743088
2017-07-24  26.750000   -0.372439   -0.372439
```

I am quite new to coding so im assuming this is something simple but i havent been able to find anything helpful by googling

Comment: This actually does not seem to make much sense. Why would you add a sorted column to your data. The sorted one has not much to do with the original one.

Comment: `result['Sorted'] = result['pct change'].sort_values()` is enough.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i just tried your suggestion and the sorted column did not change.

Comment: All you need is result.sort_values('pct change')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it necessarily makes sense for you to be adding the sorted values as a column in the same DataFrame, given that the index on your DataFrame is a DatetimeIndex - now the sorted values do not correspond to your index properly.

A better solution would just be to hold the sorted values Series separately from your DataFrame.

---

*With that being said*, the reason that you aren't seeing any results after `sort_values` is that the sorted result retains the original DataFrame index. Then when you add the sorted Series as another column, the original indices on the sorted values place your sorted values back into original order in your DataFrame.

So your issue is precisely *because* Pandas is cognisant of the original indices of your sorted values.

To solve this, you could `reset_index` on the sorted values before setting the column.

```
result['Sorted'] = result['pct change'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you your explanation and solution helped me make sense of it and fixed my problem!